# Typescript to call ngx-bootstrap function

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to link my typescript with my the hide method from [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover), in my [project](https://plnkr.co/edit/7nwXx0yGrE7PMn2ndTyR?p=preview) I am running multiple functions and it will close all together when the user click the x button in the popover, myfunction() in the typescript will run and trigger the hide method  pop2.**hide()**.

```html
<div>
  <ng-template #popoverContent3>
    <div style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-weight:bold;">
      <p>Fun with ngx-bootstrap
              <button type="button" (click)='pop2.hide()' class="close" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <p>Trying to make typescript call the function pop2.hide()</p>  
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <a  [popover]="popoverContent3" #pop2="bs-popover" (click)="isOpen = !isOpen" [outsideClick]="false"  placement="right">
 Make typescript call the function pop2.hide()
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the code from plunker, the x button.

```html
<button type="button" (click)='pop2.hide()' class="close" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

And from my typescript, I need my method to work.

```js
  myfunction(){
    pop2.hide();//needs to work!
  }
```

Comment: Did you manage to make this work? I'm having the same problem right now.

Comment: @bananaCute yes can read the comments below

Answer (score 2):

You can access template reference variable in your class.

Your HTML

```
<body>
  <div>
    <ng-template #popoverContent3>
      <div style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-weight:bold;">
        <p>Fun with ngx-bootstrap
          <button type="button" (click)='myfunction()' class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Trying to make typescript call the function pop2.hide()</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a [popover]="popoverContent3" #pop2="bs-popover" (click)="isOpen = !isOpen" [outsideClick]="false" placement="right">
 Make typescript call the function pop2.hide()
    </a>
  </div>


</body>
```

See  I have added `myFunction` as click handler on close button.
and in component

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, AfterViewInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { PopoverDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styles:[`



  ]

  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChildren(PopoverDirective) popovers: QueryList<PopoverDirective>;
    @ViewChild('pop2') pop2: ElementRef; //this is change


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.popovers.forEach((popover: PopoverDirective) => {
      popover.onShown.subscribe(() => {
        this.popovers
        .filter(p => p !== popover)
        .forEach(p => p.hide());
      });
    });
  }
  myfunction(){
    this.pop2.hide();//working
  }


}
```

working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/abK0NeBdynkRFwcSEePt?p=preview)